# laravel orderby tow column date and number

Tags: php, laravel

i have laravel relation
and this is the model relation

```
public function get_journal_entry_lines()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Journal_entry_line','user_id','id')->orderBy('date','asc')->orderBy('number','asc');
}
```

now the result come like this

```
| number|date        |
|-------|------------|
| 1     | 2022-01-01 | 
| 2     | 2022-01-01 | 
| 10    | 2022-01-01 | 
| 12    | 2022-01-01 | 
| 3     | 2022-01-01 |
```

and i need the data to be like this

```
| number|date        |
|-------|------------|
| 1     | 2022-01-01 | 
| 2     | 2022-01-01 | 
| 3     | 2022-01-01 | 
| 4     | 2022-01-01 | 
| 5     | 2022-01-01 |
```

and the relation already order by the date first then the number
how can  i do that thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to order by `number` first, it should be the first in your query.

```
return $this->hasMany(App\Models\Journal_entry_line::class, 'user_id', 'id')
    ->orderBy('number', 'ASC')
    ->orderBy('date', 'ASC');
```

If the `number` field is stored as string, you can use the following query :

```
return $this->hasMany(App\Models\Journal_entry_line::class, 'user_id', 'id')
    ->orderByRaw('number * 1 ASC')
    ->orderBy('date', 'ASC');
```

Comment: when i use your code its like this 1,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,2,20,21,22, not 1,2,3,4

Comment: It looks like your numbers are not saved as INT in your table. I've edited the answer to order properly your numbers even if the type is string.